Decode BLE Radiation characteristics value to micro sievert
I am using a BLE device to read radiation and get it on my system, but I am stuck on how to parse the encoded value returning from temperature characteristics value.
I am using a dosimeter bluetooth
I am getting 0x21 0x19 in response from the BLE device, and I am supposed to convert it to exactly 98 micro sievert. some more readings are:
Characteristics value: 0x1E 0x27 Device Reading: 9 micro sievert
Characteristics value: 0x1D 0x24 Device Reading: 8 micro sievert
Characteristics value: 0x1A 0x03 Device Reading: 5 micro sievert
Characteristics value: 0x1B 0x0F Device Reading: 6 micro sievert
Characteristics value: 0x1C 0x15 Device Reading: 7 micro sievert
So, need help to find out the correlation between the required radiation and the encoded value being sent from the device.

If your device does not meet the Bluetooth specification, contact the manufacturer or read the operating instructions. I have never seen anyone here with a working crystal ball.

Do you have the uuid's of the service and characteristic you are trying to decode?

Yes I Have. For the service : "04ee1400-ad96-4b5f-8ad4-cf552beaced0" and for the characteristic : "04ee1401-ad96-4b5f-8ad4-cf552beaced0"

@batviel  google returns 0 hits for the UUIDs you specified, so it remains to contact the manufacturer or hope that there is corresponding documentation in the operating instructions.

@Risto thank you for help, the manufacturer won't give me documentation that's why I posted here... and he don't gave me the operating instructions because it doesn't exist

@batviel  this is important information that you should have added to your question.

This could be solved mathematically, please provide some more readings to determine a precise relationship between the values.

The values could also be encrypted or otherwise obscured to prevent "normal" users from using the data without the official app...
